# Can i use Pivot for this?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with the data below.

```
ID   | NAME | DPT | Country | School  | Course
-------------------------------------------------------------------
8888 | John | ABC | Japan   | ABC Uni | English
8888 | John | ABC | Japan   | ABC Uni | Engineering
8888 | John | ABC | England | EFG Uni | IS
8888 | John | XYZ | Japan   | ABC Uni | English
8888 | John | XYZ | Japan   | ABC Uni | Engineering
8888 | John | XYZ | England | EFG Uni | IS
```

I wan the table to be like this.

```
ID   | NAME | DPT | Country1 | School1 | Course1 | Country2 | School2 | Course2     | Country3 | School3 | Course3
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
8888 | John | ABC | Japan    | ABC Uni | English | Japan    | ABC Uni | Engineering | England  | EFG Uni | IS
8888 | John | XYZ | England  | ABC Uni | English | Japan    | ABC Uni | Engineering | England  | EFG Uni | IS
```

It should be sorted by the DPT, and the Country, School and Course should be seperated into Country1, Country2 etc as shown above. How can i achieve this? Please kindly advice. Thanks.

```
CREATE TABLE #temp(
    [Id] [varchar](200) NULL,
    [Name] [varchar](200) NULL,
    [Department] [varchar](200) NULL,
    [UD_Country] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [UD_School] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [UD_Course] [varchar](50) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]


INSERT INTO #temp VALUES 
('8888','John', 'ABC','Japan', 'ABC University', 'English'),
('8888','John', 'ABC','Japan', 'ABC University', 'Engineering'),
('8888','John', 'ABC','England', 'EFG University', 'IS'),
('8888','John', 'XYZ','Japan', 'ABC University', 'English'),
('8888','John', 'XYZ','Japan', 'ABC University', 'Engineering'),
('8888','John', 'XYZ','England', 'EFG University', 'IS')
```

Comment: what if another row is added in the source, do you create 3 columns more?

Comment: @BhupeshC Nope. It will only have 3 columns.  Country1, School1,Course1, Country2, School2,Course2, Country3, School3,Course3. This will be fix

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
WITH TempWithCountrySeqeunce AS (
    SELECT Id
         , Name
         , Department
         , UD_Country
         , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Id, Name, Department ORDER BY Id) AS CountrySequence 
         , UD_School
         , UD_Course
    FROM #temp
)
SELECT Id
      ,Name
      ,Department
      ,MAX(CASE WHEN CountrySequence = 1 THEN UD_Country END) AS Country1
      ,MAX(CASE WHEN CountrySequence = 1 THEN UD_School END) AS School1
      ,MAX(CASE WHEN CountrySequence = 1 THEN UD_Course END) AS Course1
      ,MAX(CASE WHEN CountrySequence = 2 THEN UD_Country END) AS Country2
      ,MAX(CASE WHEN CountrySequence = 2 THEN UD_School END) AS School2
      ,MAX(CASE WHEN CountrySequence = 2 THEN UD_Course END) AS Course2
FROM TempWithCountrySeqeunce  
GROUP BY Id
        ,Name
        ,Department
```

Add more columns as needed